# Displaying buses from a transport network (newbie)

Tags: web-mapping, routing, transportation, storage

First of all, I'm noob in this subject so please give me some advice.

I'd like to develop something like http://traintimes.org.uk/map/london-buses/#73 but with my own city.
Unfortunately our MTA doesnt provide TFL-like feeds, but I can get some data in realtime such as:
"Line 1, Stop 1, next bus is at 500m, another at 1000m."

1- I'd like to know how do I store and display lines and stops (using leafleat or another tool you could recommend)

2- How do I show buses, if I have the distance in meters the bus from any stop.

The page will reload manually at first.
Thanks!!

Comment: "but with my own city." Which City?

Comment: Argentina http://maps.google.com/landing/transit/cities/#SouthAmerica

Comment: The city is Rosario, Argentina. The URL where I get the info is http://www.etr.gov.ar/cuandollega.php as far as I know they won't publish it to Google Transit.